# Check mp4 integrity in c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a big collection of MP4 files and an unstable internet connection so I use [this batch file](https://superuser.com/a/1241089) to check for the files integrity.

Having posted [this primitive code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/241369/223101) and received valuable reviews, I decided to take into consideration as much as I can, especially not mixing C code unless when using Windows API  and implement the said batch file using that code as the basis.

This program works in CMD it takes a path to MP4 location as argument.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

#ifndef INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES
#define INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES ((DWORD)-1)
#endif

bool DirectoryExists(const std::string& path)
{
   DWORD present = GetFileAttributesA(path.c_str());

   if (present == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES)
          return false;

   if (present & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
          return true;

   return false;
}

std::string replace (const std::string& path)
{
   std::string in = path;
   std::replace(in.begin(), in.end(), '\\', '/');
   return in;
}

void findVideos (std::string& fspath)
{
   while(*(fspath.rbegin()) =='/')  //to get rid of trailing '/' like a user inputs path/to/file//////\\\
       fspath.pop_back();

   size_t i=1;
   WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
   std::string destpath = fspath + std::string("/")+ std::string("*.mp4");
   std::string ffmpegPath = "ffmpeg.exe -v error -f null - -i ";

   HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(destpath.c_str(), &FindFileData);

   if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
        do 
          {
            std::string fullpath = std::string(fspath)+std::string("/")+std::string(FindFileData.cFileName);
            std::cout<<i<<"-"<<"Checking "<<fullpath<<" for errors"<<std::endl;
            std::string command = ffmpegPath +std::string("\"")+fullpath+std::string("\"");
            system(command.c_str());
            i++;
          } 
        while(FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));
   }
   FindClose(hFind);      
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    const char* path = argv[1];

    if (path == nullptr) 
    {
        std::cout<<"No path provided"<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    } 
    else  
        if ( DirectoryExists(path) )
           std::cout<<"Provided path is: "<<path<<std::endl;
        else 
             {
             std::cout<<"Path doesn't exist"<<std::endl;
             return 0;
             }

   std::string fspath;
   fspath = replace(path);
   findVideos (fspath);
   return 0;
}
```

The code is working, I am open to criticism and any way to improve it especially if I work in a professional company and asked to implement such program.

EDIT: Please forgive my ignorance about indentation and other programming paradigms, I graduated a year ago and failed to get an internship or a job in the domain. I tried to go with the comments as much as I can after reading some articles about indentations.

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation before receiving your first review? Consistent indentation inside curly braces (whether it's the usual 4 spaces per level, or 2 spaces, or even 1 or 3 or whatever) is important for readability.  (But once someone's reviewed the code, it's too late to edit it, because you might invalidate their comments.)

Comment: <s>Why do you have code outside a function?</s> Oh, wait, there's just no indentation.

Comment: Do yourself and many others a favor by getting a C/C++ editor that automatically indents for you. There are some that are free, such as Visual Studio Community(https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) and Eclipse (https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/). There are also some that don't cost that much such as CLion by JetBrains https://www.jetbrains.com/. In addition to auto indent, they will help you with auto complete for variables and function names.

Comment: I have Visual Studio, but I am using Notepad to learn from scratch, I will read about proper indentation, but my lack of experience is failing me seeing anything catastrophic in my code, please point the unacceptable parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Missing Header File

You need to include `algorithm` so that `std::replace()` can be accessed.

### Error Checking

Rather than checking if `argv[1]` is null, it might be better to use `argc` in the error check. If `argc` is not greater than 1 than there is an error. This is what `argc` is meant to be used for, as well as for a loop control when there are more arguments. It might be good to give an example of the proper program call as part of the error message.

The `else` that follows the error check is not necessary because of the `return` statement.

The first `return` statement in `main()` should not return zero, it should return 1 to indicate a failure. What might be even better is to include `cstdlib` and use the system defined symbols [EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/EXIT_status).

It would be better to report errors to std::cerr.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc <= 1)
    {
        std::cerr << "No path provided" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    const char* path = argv[1];
    if (!DirectoryExists(path))
    {
        std::cerr << "Path doesn't exist" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << "Provided path is: " << path << std::endl;

    std::string fspath;
    fspath = replace(path);
    findVideos(fspath);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Horizontal Spacing

A best practice in many programming languages is to put spaces between operators and operands, this makes the code much more readable and maintainable:

```
void findVideos (std::string& fspath) {
    while (*(fspath.rbegin()) == '/')
    {
        fspath.pop_back();
    }

    size_t i = 1;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    std::string destpath = fspath + std::string("/") + std::string("*.mp4");
    std::string ffmpegPath = "ffmpeg.exe -v error -f null - -i ";

    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(destpath.c_str(), &FindFileData);

    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            std::string fullpath = std::string(fspath)+std::string("/") + std::string(FindFileData.cFileName);
            std::cout << i << "-" << "Checking " << fullpath << " for errors" << std::endl;
            std::string command = ffmpegPath +std::string("\"") + fullpath+std::string("\"");
            system(command.c_str());
            i++;
        }
        while(FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));
    }
    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

### Prefer Modern C++ `constexpr` Over `#define`

In C++ creating a constant using `constexpr` is preferred over a macro because it it type safe and a macro is not type safe.

```
#ifndef INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES
constexpr DWORD INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES = ((DWORD)-1);
#endif
```

### Indentation

It would be better not to mix spaces with tabs when indenting. Many programmers use 4 spaces for indenting, by default a tab is 8 spaces. This can lead to inconsistent indentation as demonstrated in the function `bool DirectoryExists(const std::string& path)` in the question. An IDE such as Visual Studio allows you to set the number of spaces used in a tab to prevent this problem, where `notepad` does not do this.

### Replace

It's not clear that the function `std::string replace (const std::string& path)` since windows understand both the forward and backward slash in file specifications.

Comment: Thanks for your time and notes taken for all points, just 2 clarifications. std::replace is working with the current file without other includes, I am using Digital Mars as compiler (the same reason I use notepad) to learn about compilers, a task not easy with a 2 GB one like LLVM or MSVC.

Comment: As for the replace function, at least in my case, giving a path like c:\Windows\system32 doesn't work, either replace '\' by '/' or the path should be like C:\\Windows\\System32, but is it professional to big software companies like MS, Oracle, Google...?

Comment: If you're learning about compilers a good source might be the Dragon book https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools. Also look into parser generators such as YACC and Bison. Parser generators generally use a push down automata (state machine coupled with a stack).